# Webscraping England Hockey Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to BeautifulSoup to get the table found in this link: https://gms.englandhockey.co.uk/fixtures-and-results/competitions.php?comp=4154007

It's an England Hockey website and basically I want to download the table and put it in a DataFrame, and also eventually get the fixtures as well.

Whenever I try and find the right `div` or `table`, it returns `None`.

Here's what I have tried:

```
url = "https://gms.englandhockey.co.uk/fixtures-and-results/club.php?id=Royal%20Holloway%20HC&prev=4153800"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
```

I have tried to find the `div` the table is within, but it returns `None`.

```
bread_crumbs = soup.find("div", class_="container")
print(bread_crumbs
```

Again, I try to find the `table` but it returns `None`.

```
bread_crumbs = soup.find("table")
print(bread_crumbs)
```

If anyone can suggest a way to access the table, I would be grateful! It might be that Selenium would be better for this, but I haven't used Selenium yet so I am not sure how it would start.

As you can see from the link, it's a php website, so could this be part of the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Because to access this site you must agree to the use of cookies, and accept their terms and condition

replace request with below code and try again

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://gms.englandhockey.co.uk/fixtures-and-results/club.php?id=Royal%20Holloway%20HC&prev=4153800"

headers = {
  'Cookie': 'visitor-id=vPF0YU5Q; visitor-id-2=bQJHxVCjcBs4Qlmoy72Wzw%3D%3D; ImportantCookie=0; consentCookie=1; ImportantCookie=0; visitor-id=vPF0YUxZ; visitor-id-2=ZrPCssshUkv7rwB6MVkM2A%3D%3D'
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

bread_crumbs = soup.find("table")
print(bread_crumbs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let Selenium render the page then pull, or need to use the Cookie in the headers.

Both solutions provided work. The difference in mine is it utilizes a Session to create the cookie, as opposed to hard coding it.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

# Crerate the Session and acces the site to aquire the cookies
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('https://gms.englandhockey.co.uk/fixtures-and-results/', headers=headers)

# Create the cookie string to be used in the ehaders
cookies = response.cookies.get_dict()
cookieStr = 'consentCookie=1;'
for k, v in cookies.items():
    cookieStr += f'{k}={v};'

headers.update({'Cookie':cookieStr})

# Go get the tables
url = 'https://gms.englandhockey.co.uk/fixtures-and-results/club.php?id=Royal%20Holloway%20HC&prev=4153800'
response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)

for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
for df in dfs:
    print(df.to_string())
     Date   Time                         Competition               Home Team             Away Team                         Venue  Officials
0  12-Mar  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks    Royal Holloway 1 (F)      Addiscombe 1 (F)                           NaN        NaN
1     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks  Fleet And Ewshot 4 (M)  Royal Holloway 1 (M)  Army Hockey Centre - Pitch 2        NaN
2  19-Mar  10:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks             Oxted 2 (F)  Royal Holloway 1 (F)                  Oxted School        NaN
3     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks    Royal Holloway 1 (M)          Woking 6 (M)                           NaN        NaN
4  26-Mar  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks    Royal Holloway 1 (F)           Epsom 4 (F)                           NaN        NaN
5  02-Apr    NaN  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks         Guildford 4 (F)  Royal Holloway 1 (F)                           NaN        NaN
6     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks    Royal Holloway 1 (M)       Cranleigh 2 (M)                           NaN        NaN
      Date   Time                         Competition                               Home Team   Score                               Away Team                               Venue
0   05-Mar  14:15  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks             Aldershot And Farnham 3 (F)   1 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                           Heath End
1      NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   2 : 2                             Epsom 7 (M)                                 NaN
2   26-Feb  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   1 : 7                            Woking 4 (F)                                 NaN
3      NaN  10:00    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                            Kenley 3 (M)   0 : 7                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)  Warlingham County Secondary School
4   12-Feb  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Reigate Priory 3 (F)     NaN                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                     St Bedes School
5      NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   8 : 1                    Reigate Priory 6 (M)                                 NaN
6   05-Feb  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)     NaN                            Horley 1 (F)                                 NaN
7      NaN  10:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                            Horley 3 (M)   0 : 3                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)    Hurstpierpoint College - Pitch 2
8   29-Jan    NaN  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                      Kenley 1 (F) (HWO)   5 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                                 NaN
9      NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks              Royal Holloway 1 (M) (HWO)   5 : 0                     Old Reigatian 3 (M)                                 NaN
10  22-Jan  10:00  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   0 : 4                         Cranleigh 1 (F)          Cranleigh School - Pitch 1
11     NaN  15:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks  Croydon & Old Whitgiftian Rustlers (M)   1 : 4                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)            Monks Hill Sports Centre
12  15-Jan  11:00  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks         Ashford (Middlesex) 1 (F) (HWO)   5 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)         Ashford (Middx) Hockey Club
13     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   2 : 0                    Sanderstead Cats (M)                                 NaN
14  11-Dec    NaN  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   0 : 7                         Guildford 4 (F)                                 NaN
15     NaN  10:00    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                         Cranleigh 2 (M)   1 : 1                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)          Cranleigh School - Pitch 1
16  04-Dec  09:45  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                             Epsom 4 (F)   3 : 1                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)         Epsom HC - Old Schools Lane
17  27-Nov  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   1 : 3                             Oxted 2 (F)                                 NaN
18     NaN  11:00    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                            Woking 6 (M)   2 : 4                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)                 Woking HC - Pitch 2
19  20-Nov  15:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                        Addiscombe 1 (F)   1 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                   Woldingham School
20     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   0 : 1                  Fleet And Ewshot 4 (M)                                 NaN
21  13-Nov  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   1 : 2             Aldershot And Farnham 3 (F)                                 NaN
22     NaN  15:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                             Epsom 7 (M)   0 : 2                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)                    Therfield School
23  06-Nov  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                      Woking 4 (F) (HWO)   5 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                 Woking HC - Pitch 2
24     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks              Royal Holloway 1 (M) (HWO)   5 : 0                            Kenley 3 (M)                                 NaN
25  30-Oct  12:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   1 : 7                    Reigate Priory 3 (F)                                 NaN
26     NaN  14:00    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Reigate Priory 6 (M)   0 : 6                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)                     St Bedes School
27  16-Oct  12:00  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                      Horley 1 (F) (HWO)   5 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                        Worth School
28     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   5 : 0                            Horley 3 (M)                                 NaN
29  09-Oct  15:00  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)   3 : 4                            Kenley 1 (F)                                 NaN
30     NaN  13:00    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                     Old Reigatian 3 (M)   0 : 4                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)     Royal Alexandra & Albert School
31  02-Oct  14:30  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                         Cranleigh 1 (F)   5 : 0                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)                                 NaN
32     NaN  12:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)   2 : 3  Croydon & Old Whitgiftian Rustlers (M)                                 NaN
33  25-Sep    NaN  South East Women's Division 2 Oaks                    Royal Holloway 1 (F)  1 : 17               Ashford (Middlesex) 1 (F)                                 NaN
34     NaN  14:30    South East Men's Division 6 Oaks                    Sanderstead Cats (M)   1 : 1                    Royal Holloway 1 (M)                     Caterham School
```